# Rails association between User and Profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm thinking creating a model `User` and `Role`. A user can create many roles they want to. After creating a role, a user can choose a role from the list and assign to himself. So, each role can have many users and a user is belong to a role. But this seems a bit weird because role should exist first. I'm not sure is this a correct way to establish relationship between User and Role because I want a user can edit a role, and apply to all the users.

If let's say, a user `has_one` role and a profile is `belong_to` the user, if the user wants to update the role, he needs to edit all the users one-by-one, which is waste of time. That's why I'm thinking a user can create as many roles as they want to, then they able to select a role from the list and assign to the user itself.

Here's the view:

```
<%= form_for(@user, remote: true) do |f| %>

<%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control", autofocus: true, autocomplete: "off" %>
<%= f.check_box :admin, class:"checkbox" %>
<%= f.check_box :owner, class:"checkbox" %>

<%= f.fields_for :user_role do |ff| %>
<%= ff.collection_select :role_id, @roles, :id, :role_name, include_blank: false %>
<% end %>             

<%= f.button "Create",  class: "btn btn-success" %>

<% end %>
```

I'm not sure if my idea was a correct way to do, kindly advise. Thank you.

Comment: Wired! One user changes own role and it changes role of other users! I wonder how will you know who has authority to change the role and who had changed the role!

Comment: The user doesn't change own role. Instead, the user, for example, the manager can edit the role that he created, the edited role will apply to the user that is associated with. For example, you have 5 employees, the manager wants to change their role, the manager has to edit one-by-one. Hence, manager can create a list of role, e.g. role_name is analyst, is_accessible set to false, then employee who is analyst will not have access to other features. If the manager wants to grant access, he just need to edit the role, then the role should apply to all the users who is an analyst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a has_one :through relationship.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user_role
  has_one :role, through: :user_role
end
```

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user_role
  has_one :user, through: :user_role
end
```

```
class UserRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

here, there `User` will be able to create as many roles as he wants. then you can link `User` to the `Role` he choose in the join table.

Comment: Mohammed, I follow your solution and user can successfully create a list of roles. But now I'm facing problem when creating a new user, I want to add a nested form, which is role. How am I supposed to do that since the user only has one role and there is join table as well?

Comment: use rails `nested_attributes` to save `user_role` in the table

Comment: I have nested_attributes, but the nested form for user_role doesn't show up.

Comment: Hi Mohammed, I have edited my question and added the form.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think User and Role have a 1-to-N relationship. Users can create many roles but can assign only one of them to themselves. If you want to know "Who created that role?", roles can be belong to a user too. (You need to use something like `has_one :role_creator, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "role_creator_id"`)